# Compatibility of system images between RPI 3B+ and Pi Zero W

Tags: image, compatibility

Can I start a PiZero W with a system image file coming from a RPI 3B+ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you download the standard Bullseye version it will work on any Raspberry. The RPi3B and RPi Zero2 have the same processor, so SDCards are interchangeable.

The original RPi Zero has an ARM6 processor, the RPi3B has an ARM7 processor so any locally built program for 3B may not work on a Zero if you've optimised it for the ARM7. The operating system should work.

Try it, it won't break anything.